# alert without parameter inside javascript promise

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert;
}

function myFunction2(a) {
  alert;
}

let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
});



promise.then(myFunction); //call1
promise.then(
  result => alert('abc' + result)
); //call2
promise.then(alert); //call3
promise.then(myFunction2); //call4
```

I understand call2, it is an anonymous function, pass result as input parameter and the anonymous function body output 'abc' + result,

but why call3 can show "done" successfully?

call3 has not pass any parameter to alert, if 'done' is implicitly pass to alert in call3, then why call1 cannot show 'done'? why call4 also cannot show 'done'?

Comment: its the way callbacks work in javascript. you aren't doing anything with `alert` in the `myFunction`s.

Comment: `myFunction` is a function that doesn't accept any arguments and doesn't do anything. `myFunction2` is a function that accepts one argument but doesn't do anything with it. `alert` is a function that accepts an argument and pops up an alert with that argument.

Comment: `alert;` is a reference to the `window.alert` function and does nothing. `alert();` *calls* the `window.alert` function, which blocks the thread. `promise.then(alert)` calls the `window.alert` function with the arguments it normally passes to `then` functions, which is the value the promise was resolved with (in this case, `"done!"`).